# Unable to get Django Channels Daphne Nginx Supervisor to run: 502 bad gateway

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, django, supervisord

I'm trying to traceback through the errors to find the core problem as to why my domain is displaying a `502 bad Gateway` error. There are basically no clear tutorials on how to do this except for on the [Django Channels site](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deploying.html) which I have followed to a T.

I'm running a `Django 2.1` app using Python3+ on Digital Ocean Ubuntu 16.04 using `Nginx` and `supervisor` (which manages daphne because ASGI is needed for `Django Channels`).

I am not using Gunicorn.

I just can't get it to work, server side processes are not my forte so if someone with experience could glance over this and point out any major problem I am probably unaware of I would be very thankful!

Both `Nginx` and `Supervisor` are running.

The nginx error log shows:

```
 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 86.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: myapp.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/", host: "www.myapp.com"
```

Running `sudo /usr/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`

```
2019-02-27 16:39:55,627 CRIT Supervisor running as root (no user in config file)
2019-02-27 16:39:55,627 WARN Included extra file "/etc/supervisor/conf.d/myapp_asgi.conf" during parsing
2019-02-27 16:39:55,629 INFO Creating socket tcp://127.0.0.1:8000
2019-02-27 16:39:55,629 INFO Closing socket tcp://127.0.0.1:8000
Error: Another program is already listening on a port that one of our HTTP servers is configured to use.  Shut this program down first before starting supervisord.
```

my nginx conf file

```
upstream myapp {
    server 127.0.0.1:8000;
}

server {
    server_name myapp.com www.myapp.com;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location / {
        try_files $uri @proxy_to_app;
    }

    location /static/ {
        root /home/me/myapp/src/myapp;
    }

    location /media/  {
        root /home/me/myapp/src/myapp;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    }

    location @proxy_to_app {
        proxy_pass http://myapp;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}


server {
    if ($host = www.myapp.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = myapp.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80;
    server_name myapp.com www.myapp.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

my supervisor config file

```
[fcgi-program:asgi]
environment=PYTHONPATH=/usr/lib/python3.6/

# TCP socket used by Nginx backend upstream
socket=tcp://localhost:8000

# Directory where your site's project files are located
directory=/home/me/myapp/src/myapp

# Each process needs to have a separate socket file, so we use process_num
# Make sure to update "mysite.asgi" to match your project name
command=/home/me/Env/myapp/bin/daphne -u run/daphne/daphne%(process_nu$

# Number of processes to startup, roughly the number of CPUs you have
numprocs=4

# Give each process a unique name so they can be told apart
process_name=asgi%(process_num)d

# Automatically start and recover processes
autostart=true
autorestart=true

# Choose where you want your log to go
stdout_logfile=/home/me/daphne/logs/asgi.log
redirect_stderr=true
```

Comment: I thought you said you solved this yesterday?

Comment: Yes yesterday I solved the problem of getting `daphne` to run as supervisord wan't running, now `supervisor` is running but I am still facing `Error: Another program is already listening on a port that one of our HTTP servers is configured to use.` which leads to `111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream` I assume I must be doing something totally wrong with the ports but when I run `sudo netstat -nlp | grep 8000` nothing shows up.